# Terme pour "dévoiler malgré soi"

Tags: synonymes

Je cherche un verbe qui signifierait « dévoiler malgré soi », « livrer involontairement ».

Il y a bien le verbe trahir, comme dans « son regard le trahit », mais il possède une nuance négative (faire connaître quelque chose qui nous dessert).

Auriez-vous l'idée d'un terme plus neutre ?

Comment: « Son regard le révèle » (synonyme à rechercher dans le petit Robert)

Answer (score 3):

> Ça lui a *échappé* (son secret, par exemple).

« Se faire par imprudence, par indiscrétion, par mégarde, par négligence etc. » [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9chapper). De plus, je pense que je peux dire qu'une personne *a échappé un secret* mais c'est soit idiosyncratique ou ça pourrait être une extension de sens ou un emploi régional ([Québec](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/%C3%A9chapper)).

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe *spoiler* ou son équivalent québécois *divulgâcher* ont un sens un peu similaire mais sans forcément le côté involontaire.

Comment: “*spoiler*” ? Pas connu dans la franchouillardise hexagonale.

Comment: @Personne Je ne connais personne qui ne connaisse pas *spoiler*, présent dans le  [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/spoiler) et le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/spoiler/188201#11058527) et que l'Académie [condamne](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/spoiler).

Comment: … le Robert précise que c'est un ***anglicisme***, l'Académie confirme que je connaissais *spolier* (origine latine) et son sens usuel, que j'avais cru lire avant de voir l'inversion des voyelles. J'ai un faible pour la traduction canadienne pleine de bon sens et de l'érythème pour les anglicismes… sans en prohiber l'usage, mais celui-là ne passe que dans ce sens : *spoiler **mot anglais*** élément de carrosserie… dans mon dico papier de 2008, en tout cas il est vrai que « Je ne connais Personne…  :-) :-) » n'est pas une tournure adéquate dans ce contexte

Answer (score 2):

Affleurer possède un sens proche.

[Affleurer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affleurer)

> I.− [Le suj. désigne un inanimé] A.− Au propre
>
> 1. Arriver au niveau de... Être à fleur de... (le plus souvent par un mouvement vertical de bas en haut).
>
> B.− Au fig., littér. [Le suj. est un inanimé hum., plus rarement une
> pers.]
>
> 1. Apparaître, transparaître (sous telle ou telle chose)

Comment: Il est important de fournir une référence, de donner au lecteur les termes exacts sur lesquels reposent votre assertion ; dans le présent cas il faut des références à partir d'un ou plusieurs dictionnaires. Personnellement j'ai vérifié le TLFi et je ne trouve rien pour « affleurer » qui ait un sens proche : ni l'idée d'une révélation ni celle d'acte accidentel n'existent vraiment dans les définitions.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE, @michaelmeyer.  J'ai ajouté une source puis à toi à justifier la réponse.

Comment: @LPH — « Apparaître, sortir à la surface du sol », le petit Robert — « Sur ses joues, son émotion affleure. »

Comment: @Personne Dans ce sens particulier il me semble acceptable de dire qu'il y a une similarité, mais dans le sens très courant de « avouer » (TLFi :  b) Avouer, reconnaître ouvertement une chose que l'on tenait à dessein cachée, dissimulée.) je ne vois pas comment « affleurer » peut servir.

Comment: @LPH —  [ *Avouer* induit une intention, une reconnaissance | « Ça lui a échappé » de  ‘Crissy Froth-Seapickle’ est tout le contraire ], on change le mode de conjugaison ; l'acception courante n'est pas du tout la même.

Comment: @Personne Quoi qu'il en soit de ces modalités, entre « laisser échapper qqc » et « affleurer qqc » il y a un abîme de différence infranchissable.

Comment: @LPH — Erreur : « laisser échapper qqc » ≃  « *laisser* affleurer qqc » dans le contexte de la question. On *échappe à*, ou, *on s'échappe* ; *on affleure à* la bordure, ou, une sensualité sous jacente qui … affleure (intransitif - Cf le petit Robert)

Comment: @Personne Il n'est question que de « affleurer » dans cette réponse ; ce n'est plus le même terme, voilà l'erreur.

Answer (score 2):

« Son regard le révèle » [ « Faire connaître (ce qui était inconnu, secret). ➙ [dévoiler](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/devoiler). », [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/reveler) en ligne ] ([Personne](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52643/terme-pour-d%C3%A9voiler-malgr%C3%A9-soi#comment110128_52643))

Answer (score 1):

Dans le cas spécifique d’un tour de magie dont le secret est révélé par une exécution médiocre, on parlera de [« débinage »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9binage), d’où le verbe « débiner ». Ce terme est neutre, même si l’acte sous-jacent est généralement vu d’un mauvais œil par les magiciens (de la même manière que *tuer* est un terme neutre même s’il décrit une action généralement réprouvée). Il peut être employé pour une révélation volontaire aussi bien qu’involontaire - [par exemple](https://www.cairn.info/revue-hypotheses-2015-1-page-51.htm) :

> Dans son spectacle, Robin fait des démonstrations de physique amusante et dévoile le fonctionnement de nombreux tours de magie… dont la plupart de ceux de Robert-Houdin, qui lui reproche alors de « débiner », c’est-à-dire de révéler des secrets de prestidigitation au grand public.

Cet usage est probablement inconnu du grand public et il vaut mieux éviter le terme hors de ce contexte précis (spectacle de magie ou d’arts de scène adjacents).

Comment: +1 … bien que débinage (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9binage) soit plus souvent volontaire de nos jours.